# Get the actual value of the field by reversing the existing applied regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have applied regex on my field to show only last 4 digits. I am using below regex which is replacing all digits to * except last 4 digits.

```
var str = ratingTdText.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "*");
```

I want to do another thing in that part i.e. On Click to get the actual value of that field. scenario is as mentioned below

Field value is 829812983 after applying regex it is converting it to *****2983. In the next part On Click to get the actual field value i.e. 829812983.

JSFiddle link is below

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sme7c/263/)

Is there any option to reverse the regex?

**I do not want to store data in any hidden field.**

Comment: *I do not want to store data in any hidden field* - Too bad, but by replacing the digits into asterisks, you have removed information which is an irreversible process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the original value as an attribute of the same td

```
$("div.tg-wrap tbody").find("tr").each(function() { 
    var ratingTdText = $(this).find('td.Rating').text();
    var str = ratingTdText.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "*");
    $(this).find('td.Rating').html(str);
    $(this).find('td.Rating').attr("data-originalval", ratingTdText); //observe this line
});
```

While fetching the value of `td`, get `data-originalval` attribute value instead of the `text()`.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sme7c/264/) - you can inspect the browser's rendered element via developer tools to see the value saved in the `data-originalval`